# how to set/unset textwrap in a textbox in an OpenXML presentation

Tags: c#, openxml

How do I change the textwrap for a `textbox` in an OpenXML presentation object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try creating a pptx with two textboxes; one with text wrapping and the other without. Then load your pptx in the [Open XML SDK 2.0 Productivity Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124), reflect the document and compare the two textboxes.

I tried this and saw that the BodyProperties of the TextBody in the Shape differed. Looks like you can set the Wrap property of the BodyProperties to control wrapping.

Code for textbox with wrapping:

```
        BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new BodyProperties(){ Wrap = TextWrappingValues.Square, RightToLeftColumns = false };
        ShapeAutoFit shapeAutoFit1 = new ShapeAutoFit();

        bodyProperties1.Append(shapeAutoFit1);
        return bodyProperties1;
```

Code for textbox without wrapping:

```
        BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new BodyProperties(){ Wrap = TextWrappingValues.None, RightToLeftColumns = false };
        ShapeAutoFit shapeAutoFit1 = new ShapeAutoFit();

        bodyProperties1.Append(shapeAutoFit1);
        return bodyProperties1;
```